# GNU GSL where do I find the source code?

Tags: gsl

I'm writing some code in which I use some of the GNU GSL functions.
And out of pure interest I wonder how these functions have been implemented, therefore I would like to have a look at the source code.
The problem is that I seem to be unable to find the directory at which it is located.

I know that I can find the headers in "/usr/local/include/gsl/", but where is the matching ".c" file?

Sorry if this is n00bing it, but i hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just download a [source package](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) from their [ftp](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/), for example the [latest version](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-latest.tar.gz).

This contains all files to build this library, so not just the header files, but also the c files, together with a makefile, which specifies what is compiled in which order.

Comment: I might not have made my self clear. But I've already downloaded, build the library and used the functions in a program.
Now I just wanna have a look at the implementation of the functions I've used to see how they did it.

Comment: And you can find this in the source code, which is inside this tar I linked above. You actually compiled the source code with `configure && make && make install`, so it must be inside of the tar.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the implementation on their Github page. An example of their implementation of computing mean https://github.com/ampl/gsl/blob/master/statistics/mean_source.c

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.